# Seed method failing at assigning role to user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to seed my database but I am getting this error when its time to assign a role to a user Role SystemAdministrator does not exist. I have an additional field in the AspNetRoles table called VariableName so I can't use the rolemanager to add it.

This is my Seed code

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    if (!context.AspNetApplications.Any())
    {
        context.AspNetApplications.AddOrUpdate(
            new AspNetApplications()
            {
                Id = "abcd-bcda",
                Name = "AppnameOne",
                Description = "Description",
                SecretKey = GenerateSecretKey(),
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now
            }
        );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    if (!context.Roles.Any())
    {
        context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(
             new AspNetRoles
             {
                 Id = "93547517-f40d-4479-a7f4-73e86d3edddd",
                 Name = "System Administrator",
                 VariableName = "SystemAdministrator",
                 ApplicationId = "abcd-bcda"
             });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    if (!context.Users.Any())
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Id = "bbccdd-ccbbdd",
            Email = "system@appnameone.com",
            UserName = "system@appnameone.com",
            PhoneNumber = "1234567890"
        };
        userManager.Create(user,"TestP@ssW0RD");
        var userExtended = new AspNetUsersExtendedDetails
        {
            FirstName = "System",
            LastName = "Administrator",
            DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = "abcd-bcda"
        };
        context.AspNetUsersExtendedDetails.AddOrUpdate(userExtended);
        userManager.AddToRole("bbccdd-ccbbdd", "SystemAdministrator");
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Hope someone can take a look at this and let me know where I've gone wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `userManager.AddToRole("bbccdd-ccbbdd", "System Administrator");` (with a space between System and Administrator) as the Role Name rather than the Role VariableName?

Comment: Oh! It worked! Thank you! I did not realise that it wanted the name instead of the other one.